# Examples of common programs

Tags: shell, terminal, documentation, shell-builtin

Is there a some man-like program (or site/book) that can show me simple examples of common tools usage?

So i can type in terminal `show-example grep` and it will output

```
...

For matching multiple characters, use the asterisk. 
This example selects all words starting with 
"c" and ending in "h" from the system's dictionary:

  grep '\<c.*h\>' /usr/share/dict/words
      caliph
      cash
      catch
      cheesecloth
      cheetah
...
```

Comment: Since `grep` (used in your example) is used in so many different ways, it would be difficult to find a list of common ways to use the tool. You learn how to write a regular expression, and the you apply it with `grep` or `sed` or `awk` to your _particular_ data. It's almost, but not quite, as futile as looking for "examples of common C programs" since a program is written to perform a _particular_ task (a task that you personally might never have to solve in real life).

Comment: What you may be looking for is a tutorial for composing regular expressions. Unfortunately, requests for tutorials [are considered off-topic on this site](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2642/how-do-we-feel-about-requests-for-learning-materials), as answers to such requests tend to result in useless lists of links, half of which go dead within six months.

Comment: @Kusalananda don't get me wrong, i do not need example exactly for grep. I would like to type `show-example find` or `show-example traceroute` and get examples for other common programs

Comment: Well, the manuals for both [`find`](https://man.openbsd.org/find) and [`traceroute`](https://man.openbsd.org/traceroute) on my system contains examples... The [`grep`](https://man.openbsd.org/grep) manual too contains examples.

Comment: @Kusalananda mine `man` and `info` does not. What do you use?

Comment: Yes, it would be nice if all the programs came with nice examples in their docs or manpages. But the truth is that they just don't. For `grep` in particular, there are some examples under 'Usage' in its texinfo manual (you can read it with `info grep` or in [html](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Usage) form online (and those examples and explanations are already covering ~99.79% of grep questions on this on other forums ;-)).

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/991736

Comment: @muru you should make it as an answer! Thank you!